# Adding a package through SPM with a binaryTarget in multiple targets in project

Tags: swift-package-manager

I have multiple targets in my project and I added a package dependency on the project that has a binaryTarget to a zip that contains my xcframework.  It adds it to my project, my main target has it but when I try to add it to my other targets via General > Frameworks and Libraries it's not listed in the dialog for me to choose (nor is it in Link Binary with Libraries either.

Xcode 14.1

I can replicate this with other packages that just have binaryTarget as well like https://github.com/PSPDFKit/PSPDFKit-SP.  Packages that just have source are fine.

I have tried deleting the package and then adding again after having added my new targets, tried shutting down xcode and restarting.

Comment: To where does the actual binary get added in your project? Are you using a workspace to bind projects or just a project? If the binary is added to a specific project in the workspace (and not, say, some common folder "_above_" all projects in the workspace), I've seen some weird behaviors like this. In any case, following this question with great interest!

Comment: I had just used a project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue, and the solution for me was a small hack in the project.pbxproj file, as follows:

1. Navigate in the Finder to the project directory -> Right click on the .xcodeproj file -> Show Package Content. You will find the project.pbxproj file there.
2. Search for the `productDependencies` key. You will find as many as targets you have in your project with Embedded/Linked frameworks. If your second target does not have framework yet, just try to add a generic Swift package, so Xcode will make the necessary changes for you in the project.pbxproj
3. Copy the line with the given binary linked library to the required target section/list.

I hope this helps, for me it was finally working. However I think it is still some kind of bug in Xcode/SPM.

**Update: It seems the issue is solved in Xcode 14.3.0, so you won't need this hack from that version upwards**

Comment: Thanks for this! Have you found this hack to stay in place after successive edits to target and dependencies through normal means?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it stays. Just added a new SPM package to the project (not with binary target), successfully to the first target. Then I managed to add as a usual way (using the + sign) to the second target. Xcode didn't remove the existing hacked line, but even added the new package reference right after the hacked-in line.

Comment: Pay attention with this solution.. once Xcode adds dependecnies to multiple target, it assigns different package id (duplicating the dependecies into PBXBuildFile section). So i dunno if it's correct to just copying the package to antoher target.

Comment: Indeed, @arcangel06, that's why I mentioned that it is still hack. Based my tests on Xcode 14.3.0 Beta the issue seems to be solved, the binary package framework is coming up correctly when you want to add it to further targets. Based on the Release Notes, I guess the fix was related to this:  
_Binary targets can now directly be vended as products without requiring the declaration of an additional source target. (101096803)_